# ¿Cómo hacer un comparador de tipo Comparator<Integer> en Java?

Tags: java, comparaciones, genericos

Estoy empezando en Java y necesito hacer una función que compare dos objetos de tipo genérico.

En los parámetros de entrada debo pasar una lista y un comparador
del mismo tipo que la lista.

Si quiero comparar objetos de tipo `Integer` debería de pasar una `List<Integer>`y un comparador `Comparator<Integer>`

El `Comparator<Integer>` que he hecho es así:

```
public class comparadorInteger implements Comparator<Integer> {

        public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {

            return a.compareTo(b);
        }
    }
```

Mi función es:

```
    private static <E> List<E> funcion(List<E> l, E a, Comparator<E> cmd) {
        List<E> res = new ArrayList<E>();

        for(int i = 0; i<l.size(); i++) {
            E o = l.get(i);
            if( ) {

                res.add(o);
            }

        }
        return res;
    }
```

Mis dudas son, ¿está bien el `Comparador<Integer>` que he hecho? ¿Cómo hago uso del comparador `Comparator<E> cmd` que debería dentro del `if`?

Comment: ¿Y se te ha ocurrido, no se, poner en google: "Comparator java"?. Hay montones de ejemplos explicados para esto. Cuando lo tengas hecho y algo no te funcione. Vienes, pegas el código que no te funciona y trataremos de ayudarte.

Comment: @SuperG280 Perdón, debería de haber puesto el código que tenía y esto es lo que he sacado de lo que he visto.

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres comparar. ¿Qué es lo que hace tu método? Esos detalles, lo debes agregar en la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Para que necesitas un comparador para tipos Integer? ¿Qué hace, o deseas que haga, tu método?

Comment: @StyleMain no amigo, la respuesta no va en la pregunta, para eso dispones abajo de la zona de respuestas, por eso revertí tu edición

Comment: Decir que quieres comparar objetos de tipo genérico es análogo a decir que quieres comparar un lápiz con cualquier cosa que te traigan... ¿Qué pasa si te traigo un árbol?¿Un coche? ¿Un ciervo? ¿El planeta Júpiter? Tienen que tener algo en común que me permita compararlos, o al menos tienes que definir reglas de comparación, los comparadores **por definición** no pueden ser genéricos.

Answer (score 0):

> Duda solucionada

```
  private static <E> List<E> funcion(List<E> l, E a, Comparator<E> cmd) {
        List<E> res = new ArrayList<E>();

        for(int i = 0; i<l.size(); i++) {
            E o = l.get(i);
            if(cmd.compare(o, a) >=0) {

                res.add(o);
            }

        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Lo que estás haciendo ahí es filtrar elementos de una lista en base a un valor, que es `a`. No necesitas un comparator, necesitas un `Predicate`. Considerando una lista de Integer y un Integer de valor `10`: `l.stream().filter(i -> i > 10).collect(Collectors.toList());`